I want a digital video transmitter that works like FPV but cheap for UAV?
As the title suggests,
I wonder if it is possible to use any video transmitter that is placed on the quadcopter and sends video via HDMI or Ethernet but uses a similar transmission method to FPV, i.e. the video is sent whether the video receiver is on or off.
Some might say use a digital FPV that supports sending video via HDMI. Yes, I agree, but it is designed to be low latency, so it is expensive, and I do not care about latency, so I want a cheaper solution
